# POS tags of rows of data set with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to create a new column that has the pos tag of the column `clean_word` in a data frame. This column has single words as you may see in the below picture. So no tokenization and so on needed.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
import nltk

datahitword['pos_tag'] = nltk.pos_tag(datahitword['clean_word'])
datahitword.head()
```

I am getting the below error, even after turning the column into a list and series to process it isolated and then add to the data frame.

```
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Try this `datahitword['clean_word'] = datahitword['clean_word'].astype(str)` before`pos_tag`

Comment: @alvas, perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As @alvas recommended. Just needed to convert the words into strings

```
datahitword['clean_word'] = datahitword['clean_word'].astype(str)
```